# Conditional media query loading

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

I'm  trying use to a Conditional CSS loading technique found [here](http://christianheilmann.com/2012/12/19/conditional-loading-of-resources-with-mediaqueries) but I cannot get this to work. The code can be found below (I've stripped out some parts for clarity) here is live [link](http://www.lync-star.com/m/home.html).

The media queries do not apply when the screen is stretched above 650px. The idea is use conditional loading to prevent downloading unnecessary CSS files.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

      <link rel="stylesheet" class="mediaquerydependent" 
      data-media="screen and (min-width: 300px)" 
      data-href="styles/stylemin300.css">



      <link rel="stylesheet" class="mediaquerydependent" 
      data-media="screen and (min-width: 650px)" 
      data-href="styles/stylemin650.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mediamatch.js">

</head> 
<body>

<h2>HELLO</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
(function(){
  var queries = document.
                querySelectorAll('.mediaquerydependent'),
      all = queries.length,
      cur = null,
      attr = null;
  while (all--) {
    cur = queries[all];
    if (cur.dataset.media &&
        window.matchMedia(cur.dataset.media).matches) {
      for (attr in cur.dataset) {
        if (attr !== 'media') {
          cur.setAttribute(attr, cur.dataset[attr]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}());
```

Comment: You code only runs once. You need to bind that code on the `resize` event if you want to handle browser resizing